# What is the image and preimage of the set values between 2 and 5?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define f:$\Bbb R$ $\to$ $\Bbb R$ as a floor function: f(x) = $\lfloor x \rfloor$. What is $f^{-1}$ ({x| 2 < x < 5}? I figured out the image of the set values between 2 and 5. {2, 3, 4}. But I don't understand how to get the preimage. I know you have to work backwards. It seems like the answer would just be the question itself though: {x|2 < x < 5} . The answer can be a list of values, set builder notation, or just described in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
A := \big\{x ~|~ 2<x<5\big\}
$$
Then:
$$
f(A) = \big\{2,3,4\big\}\\
B := f^{-1} (A) = [3,5)
$$

If you take everything outside the preimage, you wont hit $A$ if you apply $f$. If you take something out of the preimage and apply $f$, you will hit $f$.

But if you take:
$$
f(B) = f(f^{-1}(A)) = \{3,4\} \neq A
$$

**Edit:**

How to come up with $B$:

You can easily see, that
$$
f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Z}
$$

So we know that:
$$
f^{-1} (A) = f^{-1}(A\cap \mathbb{Z}) = f^{-1} (\{3,4\}) = [3,5)
$$

In the last equality you just have to think, which values map onto $3$ and/or $4$

Comment: How did you get [3,5)?

Comment: See my edit on my answer.